# The Death Recording

Tags: logical-deduction, situation, mystery

A woman was found dead in her house. She lay slumped on her desk, holding a gun in her hand. A cassette tape recorder was on her table. The police on entering the house saw the cassette recorder and pressed the play button. They heard a message *"I can't go on like this, I don't want to live."*  then came the sound of a gunshot
 
The Police immediately deduced that it was a murder not a suicide. Why?

Comment: ROT13(Lbh pbhyq nqq gur thafubg fbhaq gb gur gncr, juvpu gnxrf njnl gur cbgragvny ybbcubyr.)

Comment: rot13(Nf fgngrq ol bguref, gurer arrqf gb or n thafubg ng gur raq bs gur erpbeqvat, bgurejvfr gur nafjre qbrfa'g arprffnevyl sbyybj sebz gur cerzvfr.)

Comment: I have made the required edits

Comment: Looks good, updated my vote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because

> they didn't need to rewind the tape before playing it,

which means

> someone (presumably not the deceased) must have rewound it before the police arrived.

To be pedantic, however,

> this doesn't actually mean it *must* have been a murder. The deceased could have taped the message, rewound the tape herself, and *then* shot herself. I guess the police didn't think of that.

Comment: It's perfect. However, I can't accept it until 12 minutes have lapsed.