# A curious incident

Tags: logical-deduction, enigmatic-puzzle, story

You are a detective and have been for the past 20 years. Pretty experienced if you think about it.
One day you were at your office when suddenly the telephone rang. It was your assistant.

> *Tring!!!! Tring!!!*
> Assistant: Sir, a curious incident just occured.
> You: What is it?
> Assistant: A person was found dead.
> You: Cause?
> Assistant: We have figured out the cause, poor man shot himself in the head. There was a gun in his hand. He had died instantaneously.
> You: If you have figured out the cause, why bother calling me?
> Assistant: We have figured out the cause, but we can't make heads or tails of a message he recorded in a cassete tape before he died.
> You: Okay, send me the recording of the cassete tape.

Your assistant sends you the recording of the cassete tape. You notice that the recording 2 minutes 47 seconds long. You listen to the recording.

> My name is Egor Drobachev. I am 21 years old. I am recording this message before I kill myself. I just want to tell a thing... uhh... no, nothing. I love you Marie and I hope you take care of our children. I am blessed to be a part of this. Cross me how, I don't care. I can't go on like this, afterall, we live in a twilight world. Bye my friends and family, for I am about to shoot myself in the head. Farewell!
> *Sound of a gunshot*

*The recording stops*

You think there are various clues hidden in the message that the man had recorded. You can't seem to understand... something feels off about the whole situation. Then it suddenly hits you. You call your assistant and say...

### What did you say?

Comment: Since this is not tagged as [tag:enigmatic-puzzle], what are we supposed to find?

Comment: @ACB: I think this is could be a classical detective story where the detective finds a clue.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/92468/ or is the intended solution different?

Comment: @Stevo ummm no.. not quite

Comment: though it is very simillar, but the solution is completely different from the solution you have linked to, if the intended solution in the question is the correct one. So no, it isn't a duplicate of the question.

Comment: The mechanic is the same: rot13(n qrnq zna pna'g bcrengr n gncr erpbeqre) Whether he rot13(cerffrq gur fgbc ohggba be gur erjvaq ohggba) doesn't really make it a new puzzle.

Answer (score 4):

> Could it be that the recording stops right after the gunshot which indicates the presence of somebody else during his death who had been recording? Indicating that he was likely forced to shoot himself.

Comment: This conclusion was my first thought , & most likely this conclusion is what OP is thinking too. Plot twist : I can think of at least 3 ways in which this can occur "naturally" , with out this conclusion !

Comment: If this is correct then the question is unfortunately [a duplicate](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/92468/)...

Comment: Read the question once that is asked...

Comment: One possible scenario: he was so nervous he missed the first shot.  He stopped the recording figuring it already recorded what it should and fired again.